# Не стандартный перенос данных из access в mysql

Tags: python, mysql, access

И так есть офис 32 разряда, есть access с базой данных (base.accdb).
Есть mySQL и python 64 разряда.
База данных base.accdb обновляется софтом несколько раз в день, заточено все на 32 бита.
Через pyodbc получаю ошибку:

*pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][Диспетчер драйверов ODBC] Источник данных не найден и не указан драйвер, используемый по умолчанию (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')*

```
import pyodbc as sqlMS

connStr = (
    r"DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
    r"Dbq=D:\base.accdb;"
    )
```

Гугл говорит все из-за разрядности, но в моем случае я не могу сменить разрядность из-за кучи других программ.

Возможно ли вообще решить данную задачу и на python написать перенос данных из base.accdb в mySQL средствами python, и обновление их каждые 10 минут.

===>А ODBC источник в системе описан? Ну, мало ли. – CrazyElf
Вот скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А ODBC источник в системе описан? Ну, мало ли.

Comment: А ODBC источник в системе описан? Ну, мало ли. – @CrazyElf 
Добавил скриншот в вопрос.

Comment: Access через ODBC должен по идее без проблем общаться со связанными MySQL-таблицами напрямую без всяких питонов. Так что питоновской программе остаётся только периодически дёргать Access за соответствующую процедуру. К тому же гонять данные из одной СУБД в другую в пределах локалхоста через клиентскую память - заведомо тупое и бессмысленное занятие.

Comment: @Akina Я с вами абсолютно согласен, я бы вообще не использовал Access, но на фирме где стоит эта задача все на нем завязано и каким то образом нужно состыковать этот модуль где все на Access с модулем где все на других языках, "питоновской программе остаётся только периодически дёргать Access за соответствующую процедуру" вот это было бы отличным решением! Не подскажите как это реализовать?

Comment: Сначала просто цепляете нужные MySQL-таблицы к базе данных Аксесс как связанные через ODBC. Затем пишете нужные статические запросы, совокупно выполняющие все нужные операции (копирование данных на MySQL, удаление скопированных данных из таблиц Аксесс). Затем пишете VBA-процедуру, которая выполняет все нужные операции в комплексе (включая операции, которые невозможно выполнить в формате запроса). Проверяете, что всё работает нормально при ручном вызове. Ну а потом пишете коротенькую программку, которая выполняет процедуру с нужным периодом. И всё.

Answer (score 0):

Решение: поставить 32-b питон.

Нельзя связать 32 битный аксес с 64 битным питоном, единственный вариант это установить рядом 32 битный питон :)